# Correct Query to get datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has a dateTime field. How do I retrieve the values that was created in today?

**guests tbl**

```
.-----------------+--------------+-----------------------.
|    guestID      |     Name     |   date_created        |
+-----------------+--------------+-----------------------+
|       1         |     Name1    |  2016-02-11 21:32:47  |
|       1         |     Name2    |  2016-02-15 20:12:30  |
.-----------------+--------------+-----------------------.
```

I used this query in and it worked well in date data type but it doesn't work when I use dateTime data type.

```
SELECT *
FROM guests
WHERE date_created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                         AND CURDATE();
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Your question mentions one table.  Then your sample query has two.  Please clarify.

Comment: I updated my question sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

The best way to formulate such a query is to have both an effective date *and* an end date.  That is best-practices for a slowly changing dimension.

Too late for that.  So, you need to get the latest date for each guest id before a given date.  You can get this by:

```
select t.guest_id, max(date_created) as maxdc
from t
where t.date_created <= $SOMEDATE
group by t.guest_id;
```

You can get the full information using `join`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.guest_id, max(date_created) as maxdc
      from t
      where t.date_created <= $SOMEDATE
      group by t.guest_id
     ) tt join
     t
     on t.guest_id = tt.guest_id and t.date_created = tt.maxdc;
```